# Photoshop - moving text simultaneously across multiple timeline frames

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I'm making a GIF and am trying to move a text layer from the middle of the image to the bottom corner - is there a way to apply this to multiple frames simultaneously?

Comment: You might find it easier to work in timeline mode. You can convert frame animation to video timeline from the corner menu in the panel. Animating in this mode is slightly different and probably easier in this case: https://youtu.be/kO4y-kHGVpY — And if you need a little bit more... of anything, you could just as well do the animation in After Effects. Newer versions have a gif export built-in, but even if you don't have that, it's not a huge ordeal to convert a video to gif.

Comment: Thanks - I ended up doing just that. I'd never used the actual video editing feature of PS before, but it definitely was a lot less tedious once I figured out the basics. :)